# EC2 instance on my machine. I have lost key pair. But in Aws secret manager there is secret value of .ppk file. How i use that to login to EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, putty, private-key, aws-secrets-manager

I lost key pair of EC2 instance linux centos. I have tried .ppk file content copy and paste content from secret manager to notepad and save as .ppk file.
While loading to puttygen its showing file format error message.

Please suggest how to login ec2 linux without keypair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the following methods provided from AWS: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/user-data-replace-key-pair-ec2/

Feel free to let me know if this doesn't work for you.

Comment: I used method 1. Created .ppk key file while login via putty. there is error message. Server refused our key. Login as centos,  ec2-user

Comment: Can you share the full command you used to ssh.? @paragtamhane